# Second dropzone doesn't listen to events

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using DropzoneJS for my file uploading and I stumbled upon an issue of which I don't know the answer to.

I have basically two dropzones: One for multiple files and one for a single file. The single file version is meant to replace an uploaded file with a different one, hence it only allows one file to be uploaded while the first one allows multiple.

The first dropzone works perfectly but I noticed that the second dropzone doesn't properly listen to the 'sending' event and the 'success' event. It does listen to the 'error' event and to the 'accept' event. The first dropzone has the same events yet it works fine for that dropzone, does anyone know how to fix this?

The code of interest is here below.

**Dropzones**

```js
Dropzone.options.requestFileUpload = {
       init: function(){
           this.on('error', function (file, response) {
                console.log("error");
            }),
           this.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
               if (file.accepted)
                    formData.append('id', 'uploadFile');
            }),
           this.on('success', function (file, response) {
                console.log("success!");
            })
        },
        accept: function(file, done){
           console.log('file accepted!');
        },
        acceptedFiles: ".dxf",
        previewsContainer: false,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        createImageThumbnails: false
    }

    Dropzone.options.requestFileEdit = {
      init: function(){
          this.on('error', function (file, response) {
             //fired
          }),
          this.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
              // not fired
              console.log("SENDING");
              if (file.accepted)
                 formData.append('id', 'uploadFile');
          }),
          this.on('success', function(file, response){
              // not fired
              console.log('SUCCESS'); 
          })
      },
      accept: function(file, done){
        //fired
      },
      maxFiles: 1,
      acceptedFiles: ".dxf",
      previewsContainer: false,
      createImageThumbnails: false
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <body>
       <!-- Some markup -->
       <form data-target="target_I_set_using_JS" action="myaction.php" class="dropzone" id="requestFileEdit"/>
       <!-- Some other markup -->
       <form action="myaction.php" class="dropzone" id="requestFileUpload"/>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging I noticed I didn't add the `done()` function under the accept handler, meaning the file would never be accepted.

Basically:

```
accept: function(file, done){
   //stuff
   done();
}
```

I feel so stupid..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly this problem happens, but when I played with your code a litte bit a found that `init` method of one of the dropzones is never called.

This is a solution where **Dropzones** are initialized programmatically(**[docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically)**) and in this case I can see that both dropzones are handling the events fine(*Well in the post I see only `error` handler to be triggered but I think it will work fine in real world scenario*)

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var dzRequestFileEdit = new Dropzone("div#requestFileEdit", {
  url: "/file/post",
  init: function() {
    console.log('initializing requestFileEdit ...');
    this.on('error', function(file, response) {
      console.log("error requestFileEdit");
    });
    this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
      console.log('sending from requestFileEdit ...');
      if (file.accepted)
        formData.append('id', 'uploadFile');
    });
    this.on('success', function(file, response) {
      console.log("success!");
    });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log('file accepted!');
  },
  acceptedFiles: ".dxf",
  previewsContainer: false,
  parallelUploads: 5,
  createImageThumbnails: false
});

var dzRequestFileUpload = new Dropzone("div#requestFileUpload", {
  url: "/file/post",
  init: function() {
    console.log('initializing requestFileUpload ...');
    this.on('error', function(file, response) {
      console.log("error requestFileUpload");
    });
    this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
      console.log('sending from requestFileUpload ...');
      if (file.accepted)
        formData.append('id', 'uploadFile');
    });
    this.on('success', function(file, response) {
      console.log("success!");
    });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log('file accepted!');
  },
  acceptedFiles: ".dxf",
  previewsContainer: false,
  parallelUploads: 5,
  createImageThumbnails: false
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/basic.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <!-- Some markup -->
  <div style="float:left;width:150px">
    <h3 style="margin:0">File Edit</h3>
    <div class="dropzone" id="requestFileEdit"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Some other markup -->
  <div style="float:left;width:150px;margin-left:10px;">
    <h3 style="margin:0">File Upload</h3>
    <div class="dropzone" id="requestFileUpload"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Let me know if this works for you and if something is not clear.

Comment: Hey, both init's are called for me though (else the error event wouldn't be called). Anyway, I load the content of the page dynamically (MVC), would your solution be able to find the elements?

Comment: Yes it will find the elements, but you need to call `new Dropzone(...` (_the initialization_) once you are sure that **HTML** is loaded

Comment: Hmm. How is it that my current code doesn't require me to do this?

Comment: But honestly it doesn't make sense, why would the error event work but the other two not?

Comment: What means that you _load the content of the page dynamically_ are you using some kind of framework - Angular ? or I don't know. Here in the example above only the `error` is fired because `url` is not correct. So just test the code inside your project and see if it works

Comment: I found the solution, see my answer, thanks for your help bro!